# What does v[a]++ mean? In this code, why are all v[a] values 1?

Tags: c++, vector, input

In the following code, what is the meaning of `v[a]++`? Why is it that after the loop has completed, all `v[a]` have value `1`?

```c
     int n , i , a ; cin>>n;
     vector<int> v(n+1) , index(n+1);
     for(i=0;i<n;i++){
         cin>>a ;
         v[a]++ ;
         index[a]=i+1;
     }
```

Is there any alternative of writing this code, using STL containers such as `std::map`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What does `v[a]++` mean?

This basically means that the `a`th value of the vector `v` is incremented by one. So for example, if `a` is `13`, and `v[13]` is `17`, then `v[a]++` will result in `v[13]` being `18`.

There are some finer distinction between `v[a]++` and `++v[a]`, which you can read about [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Programming_Languages/C%2B%2B/Code/Statements/Variables/Operators#Pre_and_Post_Increment).

### Why are all `v[a]` values `1`?

The line `vector<int> v(n+1)` creates a vector of size `n+1`. This vector is zero-initialized, meaning it holds `n+1` zeros. So when you run `v[a]++` for some `a` with `0 <= a` and `a < n+1`, when this will increment that `v[a]` from `0` to `1`.

So for every `a` that the user enters, if `a` is such that `0 <= a` and `a < n+1`, and no `a` is repeated twice, then each `v[a]` will be increased from `0` to `1`. If an `a` is repeated e.g. twice, then this would increase `v[a]` first from `0` to `1` and then from `1` to `2`.

Note that because the loop only does `n` iterations, but the vector has `n+1` entries, not all elements can be increased. So even if the user enters a different value for every `a`, this will still leave one entry that has not been increased.

### Can this be done with `std::map`?

You have not specified exactly what you want to do. My understanding of your code is that you want to count in `v` how many times a number was entered by the user (i.e. some kind of [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram)), and in `index` you want to track the last time the user has entered the number.

There are of course many different ways for doing this. If `n` gets really large and you know that most numbers in the range `0` to `n` will not be entered by the user, using a `std::vector` might not be as space-efficient, because a lot of entries will never be used. In such a scenario, using a map would be more space-efficient. To count the number of occurrences with a `std::map`, you could use:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;
  std::map<int, int> occurrences{};
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int a;
    std::cin >> a;
    occurrences[a]++;
  }

  for (auto [key, value] : occurrences) {
    std::cout << key << " -> " << value << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Regarding `index`, it depends on what you want to do with this data.

If you really only want to track the last time a number was entered by the user, you could use the same approach as shown in the example, e.g. by adding a second map that maps `a` to its index, or you could combine both maps into one of type `std::map<int,std::pair<int,int>>` that maps `a` to a pair holding the number of occurrences of `a` and its index.

If you have a different use case (e.g. having access to all indices at which a number was entered, not only the last index), you would have to specify this and provide more details.